# This computer does not support virtualization(Vt-x). HAXM cannot be installed

Tags: xamarin, virtualization, haxm

I tried to install xamarin in my pc but it is showing me this error when I am trying to install HAXM.
[image]

I looked up online and found some solution but my processor says virtualization not supported.
[image]

how can I use xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel HAXM isn't required to use Xamarin. It is required to use some hardware-accelerated emulator images but you can just stick with the classic ones, which are slower but work too. Just skip the installation of Intel HAXM.

In some cases it is required to enable Vt-x in the BIOS. The Intel Pentium B960 does not support it so it's not an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

HAXM isn't required by the Xamarin platform tools but is used for the accelerated Google AVD emulator x86 images.  It's also noteworthy that *it's only available for supported Intel CPUs*.

You also need to ensure that Hyper-V is *disabled* in Apps > Turn Windows Features On of Off dialogue:

[image: Windows Features]

Looking at your second screenshot it looks like virtualisation may be disabled in your BIOS.  Some manufacturers require you to turn this on manually.

Restart your computer and press the key stated on boot to enter the BIOS (usually Delete).  Look for a setting there that may be listed as “Intel Virtualization Technology,” “Intel VT-x,” “Virtualization Extensions,” “Vanderpool,”

Once you have enabled this you should be able to install the HAXM driver.

I would definitely recommend installing the HAXM driver over using the older ARM emulator images which are extremely slow in comparison to the x86 counterparts.

Comment: My PC's windows features does not have any Hyper-V option. :(
I checked BIOS too but there is nothing mentioning  “Intel Virtualization Technology,” “Intel VT-x,” “Virtualization Extensions,” “Vanderpool,”